# Moving Windows 7 Backups (including images) to another drive. (as simple as cut and paste?)

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore, windows-backup

I have a network of computers that use Windows 7 Backup system.  They each send their backup to a shared drive on the network.

I now wish to change which drive they send them too.  This works fine.  However, I want windows to be able to find the old backups in case of failure.  Can I just move the files? or do I need to be more careful?

(I don't want to experiment by clicking and hoping because I don't have a dummy system on which to experiment on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is ok to move them.  In fact, you **have to move em** for a bare metal restore.